# Is it possible to specify a number of columns for each row in facet_wrap?

Tags: r, facet

I have a facet plot set up with 1 graph in the first row, and 5 in the 2nd using facet grid, using: `facet_grid(R ~ C)`

Apologies, I cannot yet post images so this is all general, but the plot looks like this:

```
[C1] [C2] [C3] [C4] [C5] [C6]
{X } {  } {  } {  } {  } {  } [R1]
{  } {X } {X } {X } {X } {X } [R2]
```

Where X denotes the presence of a chart. All others are empty. I'd like to have something that looks like:

```
          [C1]
{  } {  } {X } {  } {  } [R1]
[C2] [C3] [C4] [C5] [C6]
{X } {X } {X } {X } {X } [R2]
```

My best idea was to define `ncol=c(1,5)` within `facet_wrap` to accomplish this, but it issues a warning that only the first value will be used. Is there a different way to define a unique number of columns for each row?

Comment: Not in base `ggplot2`. You can create the graphs independently and use `egg::ggarrange` to put them in whatever order, spacing or dimensions you want.

Comment: I thought so, but had gone so far down the rabbit hole with `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` that I wanted to make sure before moving on. Thank you for your answer, I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: Is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/72867291/8412665?

Comment: Looks to be, the solution presented there should work here too.